# How to change the style of layout elements for each specific page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt.js and Vue.js project and I have a layout in it that all my landing pages use this layout and I have given a series of styles to the `v-app-bar` menu tag in this layout. But as you can see in the image on the brokers page, the styles are displayed correctly for the `nav-bar` section , This means that the `nav-bar` menu buttons are white in color,
But on the how it work page, the color of the menus should not be white and should be changed to black so that the menus can be easily viewed.

How it works page:[image]

Brokers page:[image]

The main How it works page, which should be designed in the same way: [image]

My Code is:

```
<v-app-bar absolute color="transparent" elevate-on-scroll>
<div class="d-flex align-center">
    <v-img max-width="166"lass="d-flex align-center mr-10" src="/RectangleProfile.png">
    </v-img>
    <v-btn nuxt to="/landing-page/how-it-works" text
     class="mr-2 font-bold-link-text">
       How it Works
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn
     text
     class="mr-2 font-bold-link-text"
     nuxt
     to="/landing-page/list-of-top-brokers"
  >Brokers</v-btn >
  <v-btn text class="mr-2 font-bold-link-text">Tutorial</v-btn>
  <v-btn text class="mr-2 font-bold-link-text">Blogs</v-btn>
  <v-btn text class="mr-2 font-bold-link-text">About us</v-btn>
  <v-btn
     v-if="selectedMagnify === false" icon
     v-on:click.stop="searchSelected()">
    <v-icon color="white">
        mdi-magnify
    </v-icon>
 </v-btn>

 <v-text-field
    v-else
    flat
    color="#ffffff"
    autofocus
    hide-details
    rounded
    height="40"
    filled
    dense
    single-line
    clearable
    placeholder="Search">
 </v-text-field>
</div>
</v-app-bar>
```

My CSS Code is:

```
.font-bold-link-text {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Comment: I think you can use `style scoped` for your purpose. On the other hand, Could you please share more information about your `pages` and `layout` and `components` that you have? Maybe you could use `v-bin:class` for specific styles on each page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Iman said in the comments, you can use a scoped style on the page where you have the problem.

Otherwise, another way is to create a dark class that is bind to a var. And you set it to true on the page where you need the black buttons. That way, you can have your style in a global stylesheet.

Something like :

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<v-btn text class="mr-2 font-bold-link-text">Light button</v-btn>
<v-btn text class="mr-2 font-bold-link-text" :class="dark: dark">Dark button</v-btn>
<script>
export default {
  data(){
  return{
    dark: true,
  }
  },
}
</script>
<style scoped>
.font-bold-link-text{
  padding: 8px 16px;
  color: black;
  background: white;
}
.dark{
  padding: 8px 16px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I did it the way you said and I got the result
Thank